# Run function for multiple HTML instances

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, addeventlistener

I have a couple of div and each have a countdown bar. The bar works for the first div only. I'm trying to get it to work on all the divs.

I've tried adding an 'load' event listener for an array of all the HTML elements. But the function doesn't seem to trigger. I know I'm missing something pretty basic but bear with me, I'm trying to figure out the logic behind all of it.

Is there anything I am missing? Pasted in the full snippet below. Thanks!

```js
const today = new Date()
const tomorrow = new Date(today)
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1)
tomorrow.setHours(12, 00)
today.setHours(12, 00)
//Get all divs with carousel-class cell
var offers = document.querySelector(".carousel-cell")
offers.addEventListener("load", updateTime, false)

// Set countdown date
var countDownDate = today.getTime()

// Update the count down every 1 second

function updateTime(e) {
  var x = setInterval(function () {
    alert("works")
    // Get today's date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime()

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60))
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60))
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)

    // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("timebar").innerHTML = "Valabil inca " + hours + "ore " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s "
    
    // Make progress bar move
    var timeleft = hours * 60 + minutes
    console.log(timeleft)
    progress(timeleft, 360, $("#progressBar"))

    // If the count down is finished, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(x)
      document.getElementById("timebar").innerHTML = "Oferta a expirat"
    }
  }, 1000)
}

function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {
  var progressBarWidth = (timeleft * $element.width()) / timetotal
  console.log(`width: ${$element.width()} px  |  time left: ${timeleft} sec`)
  $element.find("div").animate(
    {
      width: progressBarWidth
    },
    timeleft == timetotal ? 0 : 1000,
    "linear"
  )

  if (timeleft > 0) {
    setTimeout(progress, 1000, timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element)
  }
}

/*
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar")
  var width = 100
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10)
  function frame() {
    if (width <= 0) {
      clearInterval(id)
    } else {
      width -= 1
      elem.style.width = width + "%"
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = width * 1 + "%"
    }
  }
}

function openTab(tabName) {
  var i
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab")
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none"
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block"
} */
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, x, tablinks
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab")
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none"
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink")
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" bg-light-yellow", "")
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block"
  evt.currentTarget.className += " bg-light-yellow"
}

document.addEventListener(
  "DOMContentLoaded",
  () => {
    //...get the button
    let btn = document.querySelector("#defaultOpen")

    //...trigger the click event on page enter
    btn.click()
  },
  false
)
```

```css
#progressBar div {
  background: gray;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title> </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tachyons@4.12.0/css/tachyons.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/egoist-ty/main.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.css" />

  <!-- partial -->
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.js"></script>
  <script src="/egoist-ty/timebar.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d545d9c4c7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <body class="cf bg-black" style="background: url(/egoist-ty/images/background-min.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover;">
   

    <div class="cf center w-100 w-70-l sans-serif">
      <div class="carousel tab" id="11" data-flickity='{ "wrapAround": false , "groupCells":true , "prevNextButtons":false}'>
        <div class="carousel-cell w5 ma1">
          <article class="center bg-white br3 pa2 pa3-ns ba b--black-10">
            <div class="">
              <div class="f3 dib orange b" id="reducere" value="1">20%</div>
              <div class="f5 dib w-20">Reducere</div>
              <i class="w-10 fas fa-info-circle dim fr mv2"></i>
              <h1 class="db f3 mv1">Consiliere Styling</h1>
              <hr class="w-100 bw1 b--black-10" />
            </div>
            <p class="lh-copy measure center f6 black-70">
              Consiliere Styling 75lei/ 30 Minute. <b>(15lei/15min)</b> <br />
              Intre orele 8:00-16:00
            </p>
            <p id="timebar" class="center">Valabil:</p>
            <div id="progressBar" class="bg-black-10 br3">
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <a class="f5 w-100 tc br2 mv3 link dim ph3 pv3 mb2 dib white bg-orange" href="#0">Rezerva</a>
            <p class="f6 mv0 orange">Au mai rămas 2 locuri</p>
          </article>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-cell w5 ma1">
          <article class="center bg-white br3 pa2 pa3-ns ba b--black-10">
            <div class="">
              <div class="f3 dib orange b" id="reducere" value="2">20%</div>
              <div class="f5 dib w-20">Reducere</div>
              <i class="w-10 fas fa-info-circle dim fr mv2"></i>
              <h1 class="db f3 mv1">Coafat</h1>
              <hr class="w-100 bw1 b--black-10" />
            </div>
            <p class="lh-copy measure center f6 black-70">
              Consiliere Styling 75lei/ 30 Minute. <br />
              Intre orele 8:00-16:00
            </p>
            <p id="timebar" class="center">This is time:</p>
            <div id="progressBar">
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <a class="f5 w-100 tc br2 mv3 link dim ph3 pv3 mb2 dib white bg-orange" href="#0">Rezerva</a>
            <p class="f6 mv0 orange">Au mai rămas 2 locuri</p>
          </article>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-cell w5 ma1">
          <article class="center bg-white br3 pa2 pa3-ns ba b--black-10">
            <div class="">
              <div class="f3 dib orange b" id="reducere" value="3">30%</div>
              <div class="f5 dib w-20">Reducere</div>
              <i class="w-10 fas fa-info-circle dim fr mv2"></i>
              <h1 class="db f3 mv1">Mani-Pedi</h1>
              <hr class="w-100 bw1 b--black-10" />
            </div>
            <p class="lh-copy measure center f6 black-70">
              Consiliere Styling 75lei/ 30 Minute. <br />
              Intre orele 8:00-16:00
            </p>
            <p id="timebar" class="center">This is time:</p>
            <div id="progressBar">
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <a class="f5 w-100 tc br2 mv3 link dim ph3 pv3 mb2 dib white bg-orange" href="#0">Rezerva</a>
            <p class="f6 mv0 orange">Au mai rămas 2 locuri</p>
          </article>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-cell w5 ma1">
          <article class="center bg-white br3 pa2 pa3-ns ba b--black-10">
            <div class="">
              <div class="f3 dib green b" id="reducere" value="4">20%</div>
              <div class="f5 dib w-20">Reducere</div>
              <i class="w-10 fas fa-info-circle dim fr mv2"></i>
              <h1 class="db f3 mv1">Cosmetică</h1>
              <hr class="w-100 bw1 b--black-10" />
            </div>
            <p class="lh-copy measure center f6 black-70">
              Consiliere Styling 75lei/ 30 Minute. <br />
              Intre orele 8:00-16:00
            </p>
            <p id="timebar" class="center">This is time:</p>
            <div id="progressBar">
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <a class="f5 w-100 tc br2 mv3 link dim ph3 pv3 mb2 dib white bg-orange" href="#0">Rezerva</a>
            <p class="f6 mv0 orange">Au mai rămas 2 locuri</p>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel tab" id="12" data-flickity='{ "wrapAround": false , "groupCells":true , "prevNextButtons":false}'>
        <div class="carousel-cell w5 ma1">
          <article class="center bg-yellow br3 pa2 pa3-ns ba b--black-10">
            <div class="">
              <div class="f3 dib orange b" id="reducere" value="1">20%</div>
              <div class="f5 dib w-20">Reducere</div>
              <i class="w-10 fas fa-info-circle dim fr mv2"></i>
              <h1 class="db f3 mv1">Consiliere Styling</h1>
              <hr class="w-100 bw1 b--black-10" />
            </div>
            <p class="lh-copy measure center f6 black-70">
              Consiliere Styling 75lei/ 30 Minute. <b>(15lei/15min)</b> <br />
              Intre orele 8:00-16:00
            </p>
            <p id="timebar" class="center">Valabil:</p>
            <div id="progressBar" class="bg-pink br4">
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <a class="f5 w-100 tc br2 mv3 link dim ph3 pv3 mb2 dib white bg-orange" href="#0">Rezerva</a>
            <p class="f6 mv0 orange">Au mai rămas 2 locuri</p>
          </article>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-cell w5 ma1">
          <article class="center bg-yellow br3 pa2 pa3-ns ba b--black-10">
            <div class="">
              <div class="f3 dib orange b" id="reducere" value="2">20%</div>
              <div class="f5 dib w-20">Reducere</div>
              <i class="w-10 fas fa-info-circle dim fr mv2"></i>
              <h1 class="db f3 mv1">Coafat</h1>
              <hr class="w-100 bw1 b--black-10" />
            </div>
            <p class="lh-copy measure center f6 black-70">
              Consiliere Styling 75lei/ 30 Minute. <br />
              Intre orele 8:00-16:00
            </p>
            <p id="timebar" class="center">This is time:</p>
            <div id="progressBar">
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <a class="f5 w-100 tc br2 mv3 link dim ph3 pv3 mb2 dib white bg-orange" href="#0">Rezerva</a>
            <p class="f6 mv0 orange">Au mai rămas 2 locuri</p>
          </article>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-cell w5 ma1">
          <article class="center bg-yellow br3 pa2 pa3-ns ba b--black-10">
            <div class="">
              <div class="f3 dib orange b" id="reducere" value="3">30%</div>
              <div class="f5 dib w-20">Reducere</div>
              <i class="w-10 fas fa-info-circle dim fr mv2"></i>
              <h1 class="db f3 mv1">Mani-Pedi</h1>
              <hr class="w-100 bw1 b--black-10" />
            </div>
            <p class="lh-copy measure center f6 black-70">
              Consiliere Styling 75lei/ 30 Minute. <br />
              Intre orele 8:00-16:00
            </p>
            <p id="timebar" class="center">This is time:</p>
            <div id="progressBar">
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <a class="f5 w-100 tc br2 mv3 link dim ph3 pv3 mb2 dib white bg-orange" href="#0">Rezerva</a>
            <p class="f6 mv0 orange">Au mai rămas 2 locuri</p>
          </article>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-cell w5 ma1">
          <article class="center bg-yellow br3 pa2 pa3-ns ba b--black-10">
            <div class="">
              <div class="f3 dib green b" id="reducere" value="4">20%</div>
              <div class="f5 dib w-20">Reducere</div>
              <i class="w-10 fas fa-info-circle dim fr mv2"></i>
              <h1 class="db f3 mv1">Cosmetică</h1>
              <hr class="w-100 bw1 b--black-10" />
            </div>
            <p class="lh-copy measure center f6 black-70">
              Consiliere Styling 75lei/ 30 Minute. <br />
              Intre orele 8:00-16:00
            </p>
            <p id="timebar" class="center">This is time:</p>
            <div id="progressBar">
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <a class="f5 w-100 tc br2 mv3 link dim ph3 pv3 mb2 dib white bg-orange" href="#0">Rezerva</a>
            <p class="f6 mv0 orange">Au mai rămas 2 locuri</p>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="pa3 mv4 w-100 sans-serif center">
        <div class="bg-light-gray mh2 br3 flex flex-wrap overflow-x-auto pointer">
          <div class="tc w-50 w-25-l pa3 dib br b--black-30 pr3 hover-bg-yellow tablink" onclick="openTab(event,'11')" id="defaultOpen">
            <i class="fas fa-sun di"></i>
            <a class="di black-80">Oferte de azi dimineata</a>
          </div>

          <div class="tc w-50 w-25-l pa3 dib br b--black-30 pr3 hover-bg-light-purple tablink" onclick="openTab(event,'12')">
            <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
            <a class="di black-80">Oferte de azi seara</a>
          </div>

          <div class="tc w-50 w-25-l pa3 dib br b--black-30 pr3 dim hover-bg-yellow">
            <i class="fas fa-sun di"></i>
            <p class="di black-80">Oferte de</p>
            <p class="maine di black-70">maine</p>
            <p class="di">dimineata</p>
          </div>

          <div class="tc w-50 w-25-l pa3 dib br b--black-30 pr3 dim hover-bg-light-purple">
            <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
            <p class="di black-80">Oferte de</p>
            <p class="maine di">maine</p>
            <p class="di">seara</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="pa3-l pa3 mv4">
        <form class="bg-light-red mw7 center pa4 br2-ns ba b--black-10">
          <fieldset class="cf bn ma0 pa0">
            <legend class="pa0 sans-serif f5-ns mb3 black-80">Sign up for our newsletter</legend>
            <div class="cf">
              <label class="clip" for="email-address">Email Address</label>
              <input class="f6 f5-l sans-serif input-reset bn fl black-80 bg-white pa3 lh-solid w-100 w-75-m w-80-l br2-ns br--left-ns" placeholder="Your Email Address" type="text" name="email-address" value="" id="email-address" />
              <input class="f6 f5-l button-reset fl pv3 tc bn bg-animate bg-black-70 hover-bg-black white pointer w-100 w-25-m w-20-l br2-ns br--right-ns" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The ```querySelector('.')``` method you are using returns the first matching element. if you want to add that event listener to all of your elements, try using ```querySelectorAll``` method, but that will need to loop through those elements and add that event listener to each of them.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML `id` should be unique per elements. Try share `timebar` between elements by putting it in `class` instead of `id` attribute.

```
<p  class="center timebar">This is time:</p>
```

And try this to change all **HTML** elements with that **class** using **Pure JavaScript**:

```
    var timebarList= document.getElementsByClassName("timebar");
    for (var i = 0; i < timebarList.length; i++) {
        timebarList[i].innerHTML = "your text here";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var offers = document.querySelector(".carousel-cell")
offers.addEventListener("load", updateTime, false)
```

According to mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

The Document method querySelector() returns the **first Element** within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

You will want to use querySelectorAll() instead and then loop through the items

```
var offers = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-cell")
for(var offer in offers){
    offer.addEventListener("load", updateTime, false);
}
```